# Will Spring circular dependency delay application start time?

Tags: spring, circular-dependency

I have a monolithic Spring MVC application consists of about 1,000 beans and it will cost about two minutes to startup.
Now I am researching to find out why it startup too slow. I added a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to record the launch time and use `ApplicationListener` to listen to the `ContextRefreshedEvent` and record the time that the ApplicationContext has refreshed. Then the result shows that the application takes about **80 seconds**  to finish initializing the `ApplicationContext`.
After reviewing the code, I found there are two many **circular dependencies** in the code.

I am wondering if it is the **circular dependencies** that cause the `ApplicationContext` start too slow? What I can do to speed up the startup time?

The approaches I have tried include:

- Check the `@PostConstruct` to find out if it is asynchronous.
- Adjust the -Xmx and -Xms options.
- Add lazy-init to the beans.

Seems not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Spring Boot and then you are implicitly using the annotation component scan. So, Spring will scan each class in order to create Bean. A possible solution could be use @ComponentScan("packageToScan") instead of @ComponentScan.

However, I do not know your goal but think if you really need to speed up the startup.

Comment: Not exactly. I am using Spring MVC and I have define the `packageToScan`.What confused me is whether the circular dependency in Spring will slow down the startup time.